# phpmyadmin with azure China

Tags: mysql, azure, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service, azure-china

We have a web app with MySQL database on azure.com.

We are trying to duplicate that across onto azure.cn.

So i have created my web app, created the database & added the phpmyadmin as an extension to the web app.

I've added the connection string for the database to the web app as:

```
Database=mysqldatabase;Data Source=mysqldbserver.mysqldb.chinacloudapi.cn;User Id=user;Password=password
```

and i'm trying to browse to phpmyadmin at:

```
http://mywebsite.chinacloudsites.cn/phpmyadmin
```

but i receive the error:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

All documentation seems to be for azure.com and i'm guessing the URLs for azure.cn are different.

What is the default URL to access phpmyadmin on a Chinese azure website?

Answer (score 1):

Azure.cn is a separate infrastructure from Global Azure and independently operated by a local vendor 21Vianet. Here's more info on this and the reasons why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/china-welcome

As such, you may find different endpoints for the resources you deploy to azure.cn and they are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/china-get-started-developer-guide#check-endpoints-in-azure

If you're in need to manage & operate your services in both infrastructures globally, take a look at Azure Traffic Manager: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview

Hope this help! Let us know if we can help :)